# AddFlash doenst work when redirecting to another page php symfony

Tags: php, symfony, passwords

I am making a forgot password system. I have made an if statement in which the form is submitted, an addflash will be shown in the login page. But it doesnt show the addflash.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // A password reset token should be used only once, remove it.

        $this->resetPasswordHelper->removeResetRequest($token);
        // Encode(hash) the plain password, and set it.
        $encodedPassword = $userPasswordEncoder->encodePassword(
            $user,
            $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
        );

        $user->setPassword($encodedPassword);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        // The session is cleaned up after the password has been changed.
        $this->cleanSessionAfterReset();
        $this->addFlash('success', 'The password reset request is send in your mailbox!');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('customer_login');
    }
```

Comment: FYI: There is already a [forgot password](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/security/passwords.html#reset-password) feature for Symfony using SymfonyCasts library.

Comment: Regarding the flash message, is your Twig templates setup correctly? For example to access the flash messages in Twig you would do something like `{% for flash_message in app.flashes('success') %}`

Answer (score 1):

As Bossman said, you need to **'catch'** the flashes, which are stored in what is known (or was known) as flash bag. They are very probably being sent and stored, but you are not retrieving and showing them anywhere. Once done, they will show up in the part of the html where you've put the mentioned line:

```
{% for flash_message in app.flashes('success') %}
```

I would recommend putting that line (catching the flashes) in a base twig template from which your other templates extend if your intention is to show flashes in a good bunch of pages. And remember that the `success` part is just an example, you can use that parameter to get whatever type of flash you have. For example, you can separate them in `success`, `warning` and `danger` following the bootstrap styling.